# AudioInputStream not working

Tags: java, embedded-resource, javasound

When I embed my resource and use the follwoing:

```
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("sound.wav")
```

I get the following:

```
could not get audio input stream from input stream
```

If I link directly to the file it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I link directly to the file it works fine.

It seems that you mean `File` or `URL` by that.  (Can you confirm that & which one you mean, if so?)  In that case, you'll often find that Java Sound requires a repositionable `InputStream`, which is (strangely) not what `getResourceAsStream()` returns.

The solution to that problem is to load the sound from `URL`.  Obtain the URL using something like:

```
URL urlToClip = this.getClass().getResource("sound.wav");
// sanity check!
System.out.println("urlToClip: " + urlToClip);
```